# Support for EquivalentAddins in Outlook Addin manifest

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

According to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/make-office-add-in-compatible-with-existing-com-add-in), support for the EquivalentAddins manifest element in an Outlook addin is coming soon. Is there an expected release date yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the last Community call the Outlook dev team didn't specify the release date explicitly stating that a preview set will be available "soon". I suppose it will be released around the Build conference which will take its place in the end of May. Let's see when it goes live.

Comment: Microsoft hasn't officially released support for this yet. One of the reasons, is that Manifest Changes need to be made to older versions of Exchange On Prem (Exchange 2016, and 2019). Without those changes, then manifests with the new components will be rejected by those older exchange servers, so these changes are gated on the Exchange On Prem Release Schedule.